# Passing value from a EditText to TextView

Tags: android

I want to take the value from a EditText from one page and to display that value to a TextView in another page. How can I do that? How can I store values in EditText?
Plesae Help me....
Thanking you..

Answer (score 4):

When you mention "on a different page" you mean in a new activity right?

Assuming thats what you mean, you must simply cast the content of the EditText into a bundle and sent it to the next activity. Here is a sample to get you started.

This codes should be in the method you are using to start the new activity.

For the first activity:

```
EditText txtTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
Intent i = new Intent(this, com.dzinesunlimited.quotetogo.Step2.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("title", txtTitle.getText().toString());
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

For the second activity

This code, in my case is in the onCreate() method.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String title = bundle.getString("title");

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.summaryTitle)).setText(title);
```

Hope this helps.